# Filter sub document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

`db.doc.find({},{"sections.rows.Desk":1})` returns desks list but also empty rows i.e. where desk attribute doesn't exist in rows array...

I would like to eliminate empty results. How to go about it?

Thanks!

My document "doc" has the following format.
    "docs":
    {

```
    "sections" : [
        {
            "name" : "Request Details", 
            "rows" : [
                {
                    "Desk" : "IT4"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Approval", 
            "rows" : [
                {
                    "Approval" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the aggregation framework, particularly the `$unwind` operator to be able to query against individual array elements and get the ones you are after. Currently with the way `.find` works you will get the entire document if it matches your query.

```
db.docs.aggregate({$unwind: "$sections"}, {$match: {"sections.rows.Desk": {$exists: 1}}});
```

Comment: That worked...Thanks Explosion! $unwind is cool.

My current work is at prototype stage and the data model is likely to get deeply nested and more complex. Any suggestions on resources/books where I can learn more about querying complex documents?

Comment: @Vin not really, just practice a lot. I think the manual is a great resource: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/ but it is obviously very dense as a documentation manual would be so you can't just read through it, but it is a good resource if you are looking for specifics.